# Semi-local Levenshtein distance

Tags: recurrence-relation, dynamic-programming, strings, string-metrics, edit-distance

If you have a long string of length $n$ and a shorter string of length $m$, what is a suitable recurrence to let you compute all $n-m+1$ [Levevenshtein distances](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between the shorter string and all substrings of the longer string of length $m$?

Can it in fact be done in $O(nm)$ time?

Comment: What do you want as the output?  Do you want $n-m+1$ numbers, namely the value of $D(S,T[i\ldots i+m+1])$ for each $i=0,\dots,n-m$ (where $S$ is the shorter string and $T$ is the longer string, and $D(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the edit-distance function)?  Or, do you want a single number, which is the smallest of those numbers?

Comment: @D.W. I would like all $n-m+1$ numbers as you say.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the minimum number of single-character changes (insert, delete, substitute) that transforms the shorter string $S$ into some length-$m$ substring of $T$, then this can be done in $O(nm)$ time.

The standard algorithm for computing the edit distance between two strings runs in $O(nm)$ time.  It uses dynamic programming to build up a matrix $d[\cdot,\cdot]$ where $d[i,j]$ denotes the minimum number of single-character changes that transform $S[0\ldots i]$ to $T[0 \ldots j]$.

You can use a simple variation of this algorithm to build up a matrix $d'[\cdot,\cdot]$ where $d'[i,j]$ denotes the minimum number of single-character changes that transform $S[0\ldots i]$ to some suffix of $T[0 \ldots j]$ (i.e., to some string $T[k \ldots j]$ for some $k\le j$).  The running time remains $O(nm)$.  This is sometimes known under the name [fuzzy string search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_string_searching).

This gives you a single distance, which represents the smallest number of single-character changes needed to transform $S$ into a length-$m$ substring of $T$.  (If you wanted to get all $n-m+1$ edit distances from $S$ to each length-$m$ substring of $T$, I don't know whether that can be done in $O(nm)$ time.)

Comment: Thank you. I am unfortunately looking for all $n-m+1$ edit distances from $S$ to each length-$m$ substring of $T$.

Comment: This is also called [local alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_alignment), solved by the [Smith–Waterman algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Waterman_algorithm) (which works as described here).